# Laravel 5.0: Migration Refresh Error

Tags: php, laravel-5, migration

I am an absolute beginner of laravel.

I would like to make some changes in my database. but when I try to refresh my databases, I keep dealing with the error below.

Before making this post, I googled so much and read many references. However, none of that worked and helped me solve the error.

Has anyone encountered this error before? Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'The stream or file "/web/journal/storage/logs/laravel-2016-04-03.log" could not  be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied' in  /web/journal/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:87 Stack trace: #0 /web/journal/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/RotatingFileHandler.php(88): Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler->write(Array) #1 /web/journal/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37): Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler->write(Array)#2 /web/journal/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(336): Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)#3 /web/journal/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(615): Monolog\Logger->addRecord(400, 'exception 'Unex...', Array)#4 /web/journal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(47): Monolog\Logger->error('exception 'Unex...')#5 /web/journal/app/Exceptions/Handler.php(27): Illuminate\Foundation\ in /web/journal/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php on line 87 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'The stream or file "/web/journal/storage/logs/laravel-2016-04-03.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied' in /web/journal/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:87Stack trace: #0 /web/journal/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/RotatingFileHandler.php(88): Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler->write(Array) #1 /web/journal/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37): Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler->write(Array)#2 /web/journal/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(336): Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)#3 /web/journal/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(615): Monolog\Logger->addRecord(400, 'exception 'Symf...', Array) #4 /web/journal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(47): Monolog\Logger->error('exception 'Symf...')#5 /web/journal/app/Exceptions/Handler.php(27): Illuminate\Foundation\ in /web/journal/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php on line 87

Comment: do a composer dump-autoload before running artisan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run

```
composer dump-autoload
```

inside project,  before running artisan

Add www-data group and write permission to the folder  /storage/logs/.  error is about writing permission of the log file. need to change permission of /storage/logs/.  then only the real error will be seen

```
sudo chmod -R 777 storage
```

would help change permission